# Keep checking for errors in queries

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm a bit obsessed now. I'm writing a PHP-MYSQL web application, using PDO, that have to execute a lot of queries. Actually, every time i execute a query, i also check if that query gone bad or good. But recently i thought that there's no reason for it, and that's it is a wast of line to keep checking for an error.

Why should a query go wrong when your database connection is established and you are sure that your database is fine and has all the needed table and columns?

Comment: Database crashes or link to database is lost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're absolutely right and you're following the correct way.

In correct circumstances there should be no invalid queries at all. Each query should be valid with **any** possible input value.

But something still can happen:

- You can lose the connection during the query
- Table can be broken
- ...

So I offer you to change PDO mode to throw exception on errors and write one global handler which will catch this kind of errors and output some kind of sorry-page (+ add a line to a log file with some details)